# TypeError: ("unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'", u'occurred at index 48') data

Tags: python, function, pandas, dataframe

i Have a dataframe and i want to create a function in order to create a column from 2 other columns

```
def day(data=data):
    if data['week_day'] == 'Saturday':
        return 6
    if data['week_day'] == 'Monday':
        return 1
    if data['week_day'] == 'Tuesday':
        return 2
    if data['week_day'] == 'Wednesday':
        return 3
    if data['week_day'] == 'Thursday':
        return 4
    if data['week_day'] == 'Friday':
        return 5
    if data['week_day'] == 'Sunday' & data['Month'] == 7:
        return 7
    if data['week_day'] == 'Sunday' & data['Month'] == 12:
        return 8
    else:
        return 0

    data['week_daye']= data.apply(day,axis=1)
```

but it get this error how can i solve it

Comment: Use `and`, not `&`. `&` is for bitwise anding (or `__and__`).

Comment: you should do `and` not `&`

Comment: It working thank you